# Angular 2: How to bind select field in model-driven forms?

Tags: angular, typescript

I couldn't find example of binding model-driven one-way data bound form value to the select field. Can you help me to find it?

Below is example of my non-working code with my try(Jade syntax).

```jade
select([formControl]='registerForm.controls["type"]')
  option(value='value1') Value 1
  option(value='value2') Value 2
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html you have to read in order to understand forms in Angular2.

Comment: Great. But here are two-way data binding. Now i'm looking for one-way data binding form.

Comment: there is a way. But you have to come up with specific code.

Comment: one way binding is to show the data, like text, but `select` is an input element, why do you want one way binding for `select`?

Comment: Because i don't need to reflect changes caused in form data in the template. Also i have only 2 fixed values in my select field that i really don't need to use as data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was easier than i thought.

```jade
select([formControl]='registerForm.controls["type"]')
  option([value]='"value1"') Value 1
  option([value]='"value2"') Value 2
```